# Исправьте проблему с выводом итогового ответа

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая считывает слова, слово «стоп» — сигнал остановки (оно не должно принимать участие в анализе). Из введённых слов нужно выбрать самое длинное и самое короткое (гарантируется, что все они имеют разную длину) и проверить, есть ли все буквы короткого слова в длинном, при этом количество повторений букв не учитывается. Вывести «ДА» или «НЕТ» в зависимости от этого.

```
slova = input()
minx = slova
maxx = slova
y = 'ДА'
n = 'НЕТ'
while True:
    slova = input()
    if len(slova) > len(maxx):
        maxx = slova
    if len(slova) < len(minx):
        minx = slova
    if slova == 'стоп':
        if len(set(minx) - set(maxx)) == 0:
            print(y)
            break
        else :
            print(n)
            break
```

**Проблема** заключается в том, что в редакторе у меня выводит все правильно, НО в тестирующей системе нет(см.скрины)

Как это исправить? Может что то изменить в коде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, все таки вот так:

```
slova = input()
minx = slova
maxx = slova
y = 'ДА'
n = 'НЕТ'
while True:
    slova = input()
    if slova == 'стоп':
        if len(set(minx) - set(maxx)) == 0:
            print(y)
            break
        else :
            print(n)
            break

    if len(slova) > len(maxx):
        maxx = slova
    if len(slova) < len(minx):
        minx = slova
```

У вас же в условии ясно сказано "«стоп» — сигнал остановки (оно не должно принимать участие в анализе". А у вас оно вполне себе "принимает участие"